# Calling Dapper Query<t> sometimes crashes

Tags: c#, .net-core, dapper

I have come across a problem with dapper. While trying to call

```
var item2_2 = connection.Query<ItemSmall2>("SELECT FA.ID as id,  3 as RelAgID, IIf(RelTpFak = 2, 26, RelTpFak) as Type FROM FA WHERE FA.Cislo = 1", null, null, true, null, CommandType.Text);
```

sometimes it cause a crash and sometimes it returns the new item.

I am using SQLlite v55.0.0 and server version is 3.33.0 in memory.

Registration is:

```
services.AddDbContext<PohodaContext>(options => options
        .UseSqlite(CommonExtensions.CreateInMemoryDatabase())
        .EnableSensitiveDataLogging(), ServiceLifetime.Singleton
        );
```

CreateInMemoryDatabase():

```
private static SqliteConnection _connection;

internal static SqliteConnection GetExternalDatabaseConnection()
{
    return _connection;
}

internal static DbConnection CreateInMemoryDatabase()
{
    _connection = new SqliteConnection("Filename=:memory:");
    _connection.DefaultTimeout = 60000;
    _connection.Open();

    return (DbConnection)_connection;
}
```

Use of connection is:

```
using (var connection = CommonExtensions.GetExternalDatabaseConnection())
{
    var item2_2 = connection.Query<ItemSmall2>("SELECT FA.ID as id,  3 as RelAgID, IIf(RelTpFak = 2, 26, RelTpFak) as Type FROM FA WHERE FA.Cislo = 1", null, null, true, null, CommandType.Text);
}
```

This also happens without IIf in the select query.

EDIT:
Yes it was due to executing method asynchronously and crash was because the test continued with execution and finished.

Comment: Can you edit the question & provide the exception details + stack trace?

Comment: Does the error complain that the connection was disposed perhaps? The service registration doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question anyway - the connection is created separately by `CreateInMemoryDatabase`. That connection is *disposed* after the query, which means the next time this code runs will throw an exception

Comment: I suspect the only reason this query runs at all is by accident - if a new DbContext is created, `CreateInMemoryDatabase` will create a *new* connection which can be used as long as `DbContext` remains alive. Once execution exits the  `using()` block though, the connection is disposed and can't be used until `Create` is called again

Comment: To fix this *don't* try to store the connection at all. Don't create it at all, let EF Core manage its lifetime.  If you want to use the DbContext's connection, add your query as a method of the DbContext.

Comment: Thank you all for great input. I will surely use your approaches. However in my way in the car I realized it might be because the method which contains the query is called asynchronously so the test will actually continue and finish before the code is run to the end.

Answer (score 1):

The crash was actually test finishing as the query was executed in asynchronous method without await.